# VBA for modifying chart data

Tags: excel, vba

Every week I will need to add the past week's sales data into the graph. Basically what I need to add is the week cell and sales cell. I know how to select a range and resize it but I do not know how to do it in a series graph. 
Please help! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Well, show some of your code (what you have tried and use) to introduce the people to the problem, so they could help you. This is very open topic without any specific problem details.

Comment: This kind of dynamic chart can be done entirely without VBA, using dynamic range names. Google for dynamic charts in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is well-behaved, you can do this without the usual hassles of dynamic range names, but instead storing the data in an Excel Table. See [Easy Dynamic Charts Using Lists or Tables](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/easy-dynamic-charts-lists-tables/). If you need/want to go with dynamic range names, here's an example and some links: [Dynamic Charts](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/dynamic-charts/). And here are links to a bunch of other examples: [Dynamic Chart Review](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/dynamic-chart-review/).